# Intellij last opened tab reorder (like in Eclipse)

Tags: intellij-idea

I just moved to IntelliJ (AndroidStudio to be precise) and one of the things I simply can't get by is the way IntelliJ behaves when I switch between tabs. When I have many tabs open and I navigate between the classes (in different files) Eclipse will move the hidden tab back to the front and will reorder the tabs, so that the most recently opened tabs are always unhidden, while the least recent ones are moved to the "hidden" section. In IntelliJ it constantly jumps, as there is no "hidden" section (although there is a button that shows other tabs that did not fit in the main window).

Is there any setting I can use that will force IntelliJ to reorder the tabs such that when I navigate to particular tab, it will move this particular tab say to the most left position? That way I would get a nice viewing history, where the most recently opened tab would be on the left and the least recent on the far right.

Comment: is your question resolved?

Comment: Not yet. Your answer helped me, but it's still not exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Intellij has this option. You need to use `Recent files` shortcut:

> Cntr + E

It collects history of tabs which you have been used. And you can easely navigate from among them. Just choose to which you want to switch and press `Enter`.

***Screen shot***:

[image]

***UPDATE:***

For your question try next settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's not exactly what I was after but it will be of great help, so for now I will upvote the answer. Hopefully there is some way to achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The Switcher, opens with <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd>, should help. It is like the Recent Files switcher (<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>), but it switches only among open tabs instead of among all recent files whether open or closed.